# Does this ESP32-WROOM-32E programming circuit work?

Tags: circuit-design, esp32

I am a newbie in electronics design. Currently I am working on a project involving an ESP32-WROOM-32E being powered by a LIPO battery, receiving data, and displaying the data on an OLED. I have designed this circuit based on the power circuit of the Adafruit Powerboost 1000c and the ESP32 circuit is based on the Adafruit HAZZAH32 schematic.

[image: This is the current schematic]

Right now, I am unsure if the USB to serial part of the circuit using the CP2102 works. The power and charging may also be error-prone.

Did I make any mistakes? Also, is the USB to serial circuit functional, and can it be used to program the ESP32 with MicroPython (REPL and loading the programs)?

Finally, am I missing anything?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I made any mistakes, any alternative circuits are greatly appreciated (e.g., alternative programming circuit for ESP32), thanks in advance.

Comment: TX should connect to RX and vice-versa.

Comment: Some protection on Vbus from USB could be advisable?

Comment: I haven't reviewed the whole design, but a ferrite bead on VBUS could also be a good idea. Some USB supplies [are awfully noisy](https://andybrown.me.uk/2015/07/24/usb-filtering/).